# Why does saving orders on admin screen always return a 404 error on first save?

Tags: commerce

In admin pages, add order (admin/commerce/orders/add), on saving order for the first time always gets a 404 error.  The url returned is missing the new order number: admin/commerce/orders//edit
The order is created.

Permissions seem OK.

Comment: Are you using most recent stable versions of everything? And do you see anything related in your watchdog?

Comment: was the new order created ??

Comment: Anything in Drupal logs (watchdog/dblog or syslog) or in the web server logs (apache, nginx or iis)?

Comment: I haven't seen this issue on any Drupal Commerce site I've worked on or ever during testing either. Sounds like there's some odd code interacting with the entity add form.